# How to develop a "Histogram Color Change" based strategy in pine-script TradingView

Tags: pine-script

I am using MACD-Histogram as one of the main technical analysis tool for some times now. In my experience the the zero-line crossover of histogram along with histogram color change and its fading or saturating all are profitable trading signals with high degree of accuracy on higher time frame particularly.

The zero-line crossover strategy is available by default in TradingView. Now I want to write a strategy based on change in histogram color, color fading and saturating. Which functions and arguments should I be using in Pine-script? Please help. Thanks for your time, Regards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you have access to how histogram color is calculated.

```
plot(hist, title="Histogram", style=plot.style_columns, color=(hist>=0 ? (hist[1] < hist ? col_grow_above : col_fall_above) : (hist[1] < hist ? col_grow_below : col_fall_below)))
```

So, you need to break it down to something like that:

```
is_grow_above = (hist>=0) and (hist[1] < hist)
is_fall_above = (hist>=0) and not (hist[1] < hist)
is_grow_below = not (hist>=0) and (hist[1] < hist)
is_fall_below = not (hist>=0) and not (hist[1] < hist)
```

Then compare them with their previous values to see if there is a color change:

```
is_new_grow_above = not is_grow_above[1] and is_grow_above
is_new_fall_above = not is_fall_above[1] and is_fall_above
is_new_grow_below = not is_grow_below[1] and is_grow_below
is_new_fall_below = not is_fall_below[1] and is_fall_below
```

Comment: The trade signal is as follows - Enter Long when "Color Fall Below", and Enter Short when "Color Fall Above". How can I plot these signals as overlay below and above bars?